# Xcode - Showing month names in portuguese when using UIDatePicker

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uidatepicker

I am using the `UIDatePicker` and I'd like to show month names in Brazilian Portuguese. I've already tried to use the `timeZone` property, no success though.

Here is my code:

```
UIDatePicker *pv = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,216)];
pv.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;
pv.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"America/Sao_Paulo"];
```

Does anybody would help me?

Comment: Have you tried to set the locale?

Comment: Actually, yes. Besides, when I tried to set it, xcode told me it's deprecated.

Answer (score 3):

Set the locale property on the picker to the locale you want, like this:

```
pv.locale = [[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"pt_BR"] autorelease];
```

It should configure itself correctly.  You may need to check `[NSLocale availableLocaleIdentifiers]` to determine if the locale you want is available/installed.

Comment: Even knowing it's deprecated (according to xcode) I'll try it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Clarification needed. Do you only want to set the date picker to Portuguese, and keep the rest of the app in the user's default language?

Normally the `datepicker` changes language with the user following the settings under `settings/general/international`. The `datepicker` will automatically adjust to the user's desired language, so you don't have to localize it directly.

Comment: Thank you for the info. Actually, my iPhone is set up to Sao Paulo timezone. Even with that config, it's not working, though.

Also, I'd like the entire app had set up to Brazilian Portuguese localization.

Comment: Have you looked at the [date and time programming guide][1]? It does say that you can use `setDefaultTimeZone:` to set a specific time zone for your app. [1][http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/Articles/dtTimeZones.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000185-BBCBDGID]

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to do anything. As soon as the iPhone is set to the proper locale, the `UIDatePicker` will show the proper values for you. That's why locale related methods and properties are deprecated. It relies on system configuration.